# Altering a column and cancelling the alter greatly improves SQL performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table that is roughly 5.5 million rows. We use Entity Framework and run a query on this table and get our row of interest based on 2 columsn. One FK column that has an index (`Type`) and another column (`ObjectId`) that is of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` that cannot have an index.

We experienced timeouts in our system. As a proof of concept I was going to change the `ObjectId` column to a fixed length so I could add an index.

I execute an alter statement . . .

```
ALTER TABLE Audit.Changes 
    ALTER COLUMN ObjectId VARCHAR(50) NULL
```

After 2 seconds or 2 minutes, I cancel the statement, it has NOT fully executed.

I re-run my test and the query starts to run without any timeout issue.

**NOTE**: I have tried to run `UPDATE STATISTICS` without an improvement.

**NOTE**: If I restore a backup, problem comes back, and I can consistently fix it by running the alter and cancelling it.

**NOTE** I am fully aware this is bad design, I absorbed this system and will be fixing the data type however for my own knowledge I would like to understand the behavior.

**My question**: what is SQL invalidating under the hood or what is it doing where triggering a change on the column or cancelling an alteration to the table would cause the timeout to go away? Is there a direct command I can use to instead of running the statement and a cancel.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using nvarchar(max) if your column could be specified as nvarchar(50)? Using (max) has performance overhead regardless of what you store in it.

Comment: When your query timeouts what is the execution plan? Is it any different from the faster executions? If so how?

Comment: I'd suggest you also post this question in https://dba.stackexchange.com/. You're asking about how the database works under the hood and people on the DBA SE site might know about the engine.

Comment: The implementation is in a legacy system that I unfortunately absorbed.  I understand it is not great, I'm more interested in an explanation around the behavior.  I am in the process of flipping out the column but it will require downtime which we cannot do in the near future.

Comment: Could you try creating a new column and copying the data to it, in batches if necessary, then drop the old column and rename?

Comment: Download sp_whoisactive and run it while the long running query is executing and it will report wait stats IE what the query is waiting for. This may help understand the issue

Comment: I would have guessed that there is parameter sniffing going on here, and the `ALTER` is invalidating the bad plan. But `UPDATE STATISTICS` should have done the same, so not sure. Please upload before and after plans to https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan and post the links

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce a fix I have used the following query, the key is the "WITH FULLSCAN"

UPDATE STATISTICS Audit.Changes WITH FULLSCAN